# Vassals inheriting titles below yours outside your realm

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm a king of feudal gavelkind kingdom.
My direct vassal count of my kingdom de jure county inherited a duchy outside my de jure kingdom.
I was surprised when he left my realm upon inheritance. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202226/a-vassal-gained-a-title-and-he-became-independent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
explained why this happened - rank-defining title made him independent (I suspect that in m y case because he made new duchy his primary title and declared independence due me not being his de jure liege).

What could I have done to prevent that from happening?

- Does result vary if inheriting vassal is/is not of my dynasty?
- Kingdom law (controlled inheritance/strong crown authority)?
- Would he stay in the realm if he was originally holding a duchy title in my de jure kingdom?

Comment: Have you read that post : [A vassal gained a title and he became independent](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202226/a-vassal-gained-a-title-and-he-became-independent)? Might bring a couple of answer.

Comment: Thanks, @jouramie, related but does not answer my what-ifs.

Comment: What do you mean by "kingdom law"? Are you talking about the case where a vassal is in your realm, but the law of your kingdom does not apply because his county belong de jure to an other kingdom?

Comment: High crown authority/controlled realm inheritance or things like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through some console shenanigans I set up a situation to test your 3 specific questions:

[image]
Controlled Realm Inheritance set to Illegal

[image]
Sardinia is an independent duchy within my de jure, but not de facto Kingdom of Lombardy

[image]
Countess Anselberga is my vassal, dynastic count. She is first in line to inherit Sardinia.

[image]
The Duke(Doux) of Sardinia dies. Anselberga becomes the Duchess of Sardinia, taking the county of Florens with her.

---

So we can conclude that dynasty members will still leave, even with Controlled Realm Inheritance and both her old and new titles being de jure vassals of your primary title.

---

To prevent this:

1. [Disqualify](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession#Disqualification) him from succession
2. Change the heir of the foreign title. (e.g. If he's inheriting because the foreign ruler has no kids, try to find a young, lustful bride to bear the foreigner some kids)
3. [Get him a title equal or greater than the foreign title](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession#Inheritance_Conflict) (lesser than your own title, of course) (e.g. grant  him one of yours, push a claim of his, take one in a holy war)
4. [Revoke](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Title_revocation) his title, so he can't take it with him
5. Make the foreign title part of your realm or destory it via conquest
6. kill him, and hope his heir isn't next in line to the foreign title.
7. If all else fails, make sure the title you're losing is in your de jure realm, so you can declare a de jure war to reclaim it.

Comment: what are the fonts? these are not vanilla, are they?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Could you please confirm suggestion #3 with your "console shenanigans" before I accept your answer?

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta I use [Theatrum Orbis Terrarum](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=570256235), and [Bigger Interface](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=762121960). They're both Ironman compatible.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Having a vassal inherit an equal or lower level title is a pretty common way of expanding your realm via intrigue/marriage. Bullet 2 under [Inheritance conflict](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession#Inheritance_Conflict) of the [Succession](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession) page spells it out. I"ll add that link to my answer.